# Can't foucs <a> using tab in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, browser, keydown

I meet a very weird problem, there're three links:

```
<div>
    <a id="conservativeOption" href="#option1"><div id="conservativeTitleNew" class="investButtonTitle">Option 1</div><span id="more-conservative" class="portfolio-risk-level "></span></a>
    <a id="moderateOption" href="#option2"><div id="moderateTitle" class="investButtonTitle">Option 2</div><span id="moderate" class="portfolio-risk-level"></span></a>
    <a id="aggresiveOption" href="#option3"><div id="aggresiveTitle" class="investButtonTitle">Option 3</div><span id="more-aggressive" class="portfolio-risk-level"></span></a>
</div>
```

This is the piece of code from my project jsp, if I copy this into a new html body, I can use "tab" focus on every link and the url will show at the left-bottom of the browser.

---

But back to my project jsp, it has a lot of links, I use tab to focus these links one by one, but it always jump these three links, and go to the next. But if I remove the "class" attribute value of the div: "investButtonTitle", the browser will focus these three links, but my page will be in a mess. I don't know the reason, I think the css class won't cause this kind of problem.

this is the css of these "investButtonTitle":

```
color: white;
cursor: pointer;
font-size: 125%;
font-weight: bold;
margin-left: 76px;
margin-top: 9px;
position: absolute;
background: transparent
```

it only happen in Chrome, IE9 works fine.
Thanks

Comment: If remove this css "position: absolute;" it works fine. But I'm not clearly about the reason:(

Answer (score 0):

Use tabindex attribute into .investButtonTitle div

```
<div id="conservativeTitleNew" class="investButtonTitle" tabindex="1">Option 1</div>
```

like this http://jsfiddle.net/hbuz3/1